# evitar Confirmação de Reenvio de Formulario

Tags: java, jsp

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação e quando clico em salvar ele redireciona para onde eu quero atualizado. Só que se eu atualizar a página ele faz pergunta se eu quero aproveitar os dados passados antes, eu não gostaria que isso acontecesse

É assim que estou fazendo:

```
 boolean teste = cc.inserir(curso);
 RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
 rd.forward(req, resp);
```

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi!

Eu adicionei um javascript para retornar o valor se deu certo ou não.
Esse javascript redireciona caso operação seja efetuada com sucesso

```
setTimeout(function (){
            location.href = "curso"
        },1000);
```